# Django template tag filter is showing "a float is required" error

Tags: python, django, templatetag

Hi I have django template tag,

```
@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    try:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except AttributeError:
        return 'error'
    except KeyError:
        return 'error'
```

and am passing this filter to my webpage as follows,

```
<td>{{ table.last_updated|timestamp}}</td>
```

But it returns an error, "a float is required". Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: btw, my table.last_updated is an unixtimestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `MySQLdb` module to get data from your database.It will convert your `unixtimestamp db column` to python type `datetime.datetime`.And `datetime.fromtimestamp` function use a `float` object as input params.

So you should add a condition in your timestamp function.If the type of `value` is `datetime.datetime`,convert the value to `float`.

```
import time
import datetime
print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().utctimetuple())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks amow. It was fruitful. I tried the following method and it worked.

```
@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    if value is not None:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        return 'None'
```